# Environment Variables for storing instance data

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I think that this is a dumb question about Env Variables in node js.

My question is, is it ok to dynamically set env variables , for example when the user starts a session. Let's say that I want to store a user's email which will be stored in a env variable and will be used in other parts of the website (Let's say the application can't access the user's email using any other method) .

Will this interfere with the way node works and mess up my users experience

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer is no.

Comment: You actually asked two questions in your post which's answer is the complement to the other. Please explain your answer in more detail.